iOS18 UIDatePicker The actual value will always be a month different from what is shown
iOS18  UIDatePicker  The actual value will always be a month offset from what is shown.
https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/770345
Someone else had this problem, but I didn't get the solution I needed.
Anyone help? Thanks

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
